# Can RAID 0 cause significantly more writes on one drive?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, diagnostic, raid-0

I use a Windows 10 laptop with two 1-TB SSDs mounted with RAID 0.

I see in [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/):

|  | SSD 1 | SSD 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total Host Reads | 8193 GB | 8193 GB |
| Total Host Writes | 5295 GB | 5383 GB |

Total Host Reads is the same, but there's a 88 GB difference for the Total Host Writes. Can RAID 0 cause significantly more writes on one drive?

---

CrystalDiskInfo screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wonder if part of the reason is a lot of writes to the file allocation table/equivalent, which may all reside on 1 drive depending on the filesystem and alignment of these parts of the filesystem with the chunk size of the RAID?

Comment: Is 1.6% *significant*ly more?? How is the RAID implemented? There is no "control" or parity data stored with raid0 so there should be no imbalance. But windows is bad at hard drives, so my first suspicion is something there.